# JavaScript Recursive Function Parameters

Tags: javascript, recursion, parameter-passing, binary-search-tree

I'm building a Binary Search tree and I made a function to insert new values recursively, I tried to put its parameters by two ways:

1- by reassign the parameter by assignment operator with the new value

2- by puting the new value of parameter without reassigning it with assignment operator

for me I don't see nor know what's the difference between them, I think every time the function call itself it reassign the node parameter to its right or left in both of them.
my question is why don't both ways work the same, and what's the difference btween these two ways?

here's the code for both and the output I got:

```
class Node {
    constructor(key, left, right) {
        this.key = key || null;
        this.left = left || null;
        this.right = right || null;
    }
}

class Tree {
    constructor(arr) {
        this.tree = this.buildTree(arr);
    }
......
}
let tree = new Tree([3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 7, 5, 8, 10, 9, 12, 11])
tree.insert(100)
```

#1- by reassign the parameter by assignment operator with the new value

```
insert(value, node = this.tree) {
        if (node == null) return node = new Node(value)
        if (value == node.key) return node; // prevent dublicated values;
        if (value > node.key) node.right = this.insert(value, node = node.right);
        else if (value < node.key) node.left = this.insert(value, node = node.left);
        return node
    }
```

===> this way didn't put the new node in the right place and it deleted other nodes from the tree
this is its output : 
[image: recursive function parameters with assignment operator]

#2- by puting the new value of parameter with reassigning it without assignment operator

```
insert(value, node = this.tree) {
        if (node == null) return node = new Node(value)
        if (value == node.key) return node; // prevent dublicated values;
        if (value > node.key) node.right = this.insert(value, node.right);
        else if (value < node.key) node.left = this.insert(value, node.left);
        return node
    }
```

===> this way works well and insert the new value in the right place without removing any
parent nodes
this is its out put
[image: recursive function parameters without assignment operator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.  The following probably doesn't look correct:

```js
insert(value, node = this.tree) {
    if (node == null) return node = new Node(value)
    if (value == node.key) return node; // prevent dublicated values;
    if (value > node.key) {
        node = node.right;
        node.right = this.insert(value, node);
    } else if (value < node.key) {
        node = node.left;
        node.left = this.insert(value, node);
    }
    return node;
}
```

And of course it's not.  We don't want to change the identity of `node` before we return it.  But that is, in essence, what your code does.
This line does the same as the `if` block above:

```js
if (value > node.key) node.right = this.insert(value, node = node.right);
```

First, we reassign the value of our `node` variable to `node.right`.  Then we call the `insert` with the new node value.  Then at the end of the function, we return `node`, *with its new value*.

There is a strong argument for never, ever reassigning an input parameter.  This is simply one piece of evidence for that idea.

Comment: it's more clear now, thank you so much

Comment: a great lesson on the suffering caused by reassignment and mutation!

Answer (score 3):

**unreachable code**

To accompany Scott Sauyet's answer, I would suggest you simplify your `if..` conditionals as well.

```js
insert(value, node = this.tree) {
  if (node == null)          // ..
  if (value == node.key)     // ..
  if (value > node.key)      // ..
  else if (value < node.key) // ..
  return node                // ???
}
```

Think about that `???` - if the value is not less, not greater, not equal, then what is it? Bugs aside (from improper values), it's redundant, unreachable code. If the value is neither greater nor lesser, then it must be equal -

```js
insert(value, node = this.tree) {
  if (node == null)      // node is empty
  if (value > node.key)  // value is greater (implicit: node not empty)
  if (value < node.key)  // value is lesser  (implicit: node not empty; value not greater)
  return node            // value is equal   (implicit: node not empty; value not greater, not lesser)
}
```

**persistent data structures**

Reassignment (or any mutation) makes our programs harder to think about as well. We can create new nodes instead of mutating the old ones. When a data structure guarantees it will never change, it is known as a persistent data structure -

```js
insert(value, node = this.tree) {
  // is the node empty?
  if (node == null)
    return new Node(value)

  // the node is not empty. is the value greater?
  else if (value > node.key)
    return new Node(node.value, node.left, this.insert(value, node.right))

  // the node is not empty and the value is not greater. is it less?
  else if (value < node.key)
    return new Node(node.value, this.insert(value, node.left), node.right)

  // the node is not empty and the value is neither greater nor lesser
  else
    return node
}
```

**module-oriented design**

Finally I would suggest decoupling your tree functions from the class -

```js
// tree.js
const empty = Symbol("tree.empty")

const node = (value, left = empty, right = empty) =>
  ({ value, left, right })
  
const insert = (t, value) => {
  if (t === empty)
    return node(value)
  else if (value < t.value)
    return node(t.value, insert(t.left, value), t.right)
  else if (value > t.value)
    return node(t.value, t.left, insert(t.right, value))
  else
    return t
}

const fromArray = (arr) => arr.reduce(insert, empty)

const toString = (t) => ...
```

Then if you want an object-oriented interface, create it as a thin wrapper around the ordinary function interface -

```
// tree.js (continued)
class tree {
  static fromArray(arr) { return new tree(fromArray(arr)) }
  constructor(t) { this.t = t }
  insert(value) { return new tree(insert(this.t, value)) }
  toString() { return toString(this.t) }
}
```

Export both interfaces through the module -

```js
// tree.js (continued)
export { empty, fromArray, insert, node, toString }
export default tree
```

Now your module provides a dual interface. You can use the functional module and take advantage of tree-shaking -

```js
import { insert, fromArray, toString } from "./tree.js"

const mytree = insert(
  fromArray([3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 7, 5, 8, 10, 9, 12, 11]),
  100
)

console.log(toString(mytree))
```

Or you can import the entire module through the class interface -

```js
import tree from "./tree.js"

const mytree = tree
  .fromArray([3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 7, 5, 8, 10, 9, 12, 11])
  .insert(100)

console.log(mytree)
```

Comment: Beautiful as always!

Comment: thank you so much I'm really grateful to you, it's really helpful and well designed code, and about factory functions and moduled design, I use this pattern usually in building pages more than object oriented design. just this time I was practcing data structure in general so I decided to use classes in order to practice this part in general, not only for JS.

Answer (score 0):

#1 *changes* `node` in the process of making the recursive calls, thus changing what it returns; #2 does not.  A debugger would help make clear how this causes nodes to be "lost".